# jQuery Animate Skipping Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a simple quiz using jQuery. I'm using .animate on .on to reveal new questions. Those questions are just divs layered underneath each other using z-index to order them.

I have two columns. The one on the left says what subject it is. The one on the right shows the questions. After a few questions, the left column animates to reveal the next subject.

Everything is great until the fourth question is animated. It then skips to the very last question without revealing the next one I have no idea what's going wrong. I do have 10 questions in all, but I didn't want to paste all the code. It's already rather long...

Any thoughts? Thanks!

HTML

```
<!-- Quiz Category Side -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- Pillar 1 -->
    <div id="pillar1">
        <div class="align">
            <h2>Subject 1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Pillar 2 -->
    <div id="pillar2">
        <div class="align">
            <h2>Subject 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Pillar 3 -->
    <div id="pillar3">
        <div class="align">
            <h2>Subject 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Results -->
    <div class="align results"></div>
</div>

<!-- Quiz Answer Side -->
<!-- Question 1 Subject 1 -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form id="question1" class="panel">
        <div class="align">
            <h3>Question 1 XYZ?</h3>
            <div class="questions">
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Question 2 Subject 1 -->
    <form id="question2" class="panel">
        <div class="align">
            <h3>Question 2 XYZ?</h3>
            <div class="questions">
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Question 3 Subject 1 -->
    <form id="question3" class="panel">
        <div class="align">
            <h3>Question 3 XYZ?</h3>
            <div class="questions">
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Question 4 Subject 1 -->
    <form id="question4" class="panel">
        <div class="align">
            <h3>Question 4 XYZ?</h3>
            <div class="questions">
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question4" value="1" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question4" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
    <!-- Question 5 Subject 2 -->
    <form id="question5" class="panel">
        <div class="align">
            <h3>Question 5 XYZ</h3>
            <div class="questions">
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                            <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="1" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>         
    <!-- Question 6 Subject 2 -->
    <form id="question6" class="panel">
        <div class="align">
            <h3>Question 6 XYZ?</h3>
            <div class="questions">
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="1" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
                </div>
                <div class="question">
                    <input type="radio" name="question6" value="2" /><p class="question-text">Answer XYZ</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

CSS

```
.container, .container2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4, #question5, #question6, #pillar1, #pillar2, #pillar3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: table;
}

#question1, #question2, #question3, #question4, #question5, #question6 {
    background-color: white;
}

#question1 {
    z-index: 100;
}

#question2 {
    z-index: 90;
}

#question3 {
    z-index: 80;
}

#question4 {
    z-index: 70;
}

#question5 {
    z-index: 60;
}

#question6 {
    z-index: 50;
}

#pillar1 {
    z-index: 30;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#pillar2 {
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: red;
}

#pillar3 {
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: blue;
}

.align {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.questions {
    padding-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.question {
    text-align: left;
}

.question-text {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
// question 1
$('#question1 input').on('change', function () {
    var $questionAnswer1 = $('input[name=question1]:checked', '#question1').val();

    $('#question1').animate({
        'left': '2000px'
    }, 3000); 
});

//question 2
$('#question2 input').on('change', function () {
    var $questionAnswer2 = $('input[name=question2]:checked', '#question2').val();

    $('#question2').animate({
        'left': '2000px'
    }, 3000); 
});

//question 3
$('#question3 input').on('change', function () {
    var $questionAnswer3 = $('input[name=question3]:checked', '#question3').val();

    $('#question3').animate({
        'left': '2000px'
    }, 3000); 
});    

//question 4
$('#question4 input').on('change', function () {
    var $questionAnswer4 = $('input[name=question4]:checked', '#question4').val();

    $('#question4').animate({
        'left': '2000px'
    }, 3000); 

    $('#pillar1').animate({
        'left': '-2000px'
    }, 3000);
});      

//question 5
$('#question5 input').on('change', function () {
    var $questionAnswer5 = $('input[name=question5]:checked', '#question5').val();

    $('#question5').animate({
        'left': '2000px'
    }, 3000); 
});

//question 6
$('#question6 input').on('change', function () {
    var $questionAnswer6 = $('input[name=question6]:checked', '#question6').val();

    $('#question6').animate({
        'left': '2000px'
    }, 3000); 
});

//question 7
$('#question7 input').on('change', function () {
    var $questionAnswer7 = $('input[name=question7]:checked', '#question7').val();

    $('#question7').animate({
        'left': '2000px'
    }, 3000); 

    $('#pillar2').animate({
        'left': '-2000px'
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I just created a fiddle with your code snippets. And it seems to be working fine here - https://jsfiddle.net/n17ye68h/

Comment: Nifal, I did the same. The jsFiddle seems to not recognize the left column. I think something in the left column is affecting the right. Dumping it into a code editor should reveal the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ok. let me know if there is anything that I could help with